# Taxonomy autocomplete - show results of words starting with letters written

Tags: 7, ajax, entities, taxonomy-terms

I am having hard time to explain this but this is the case:

I have taxonomy with 80000 terms (country/city).

When i type for example "N" or "NE" or "NEW" i get results with terms that contain all type. 
So for "NEW" in autocomplete i get:
Abercarn-Newbridge
Ballycanew
Binhai New Area
Bowmanville-Newcastle
Carnew etc...

What i would like is to get:
New York
or
New Zeland
or any other city/country that starts with letters which i input.

I installed and tried http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_autocomplete_settings which works but only for views exposed filter which is great.

Problem is that for node/add node/edit it doesnt work. (as explained here http://drupal.org/node/1527756 .Autocomplete circle just keeps spinning not showing any results.)

I have to use autocomplete for add/edit becouse Hierarchical select module is taking around 20-30 to load for parent and that much for child term too while autocomplete reacts in miliseconds.

Comment: I've added a patch for the tagged issue (taxonomy_autocomplete_settings) on drupal.org. Do help me test it. Thanks!

Comment: Patch works fine !